# Load Test- Video Conferencing Site like Zoom

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load

I am new to JMeter. I am trying to perform a load test on a video conferencing application like zoom. Can I achieve this using JMeter? If not, please suggest any application that would help perform load test on a Video Conferencing site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Zoom uses may be using WebRtc or Websockets as per this documentation on their protocol:

- https://webrtchacks.com/zoom-avoids-using-webrtc/

So if you confirm it's websocket, you can use this plugin:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers

If it's WebRtc then your best option is to use selenium webdriver:

- https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver
- [Using Selenium WebDriver with JMeter](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/)

I don't think HLS is used by them, but if you need a full features implementation of Video Streaming protocols have a look at this:

[UbikLoadPack Streaming Solution features for Video & Audio Performance](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/streaming-performance-solution-ubikloadpack/)

Disclaimer: We provide this solution and professional services around performance testing

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze network protocol(s) which are being used for audio/video streaming it might be the case you will be able to use a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) like [HLS PLUGIN](https://github.com/Blazemeter/HLSPlugin) or [WebSocket Plugin](http://JMeter%20WebSocket%20Samplers)

If the application is using [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol you can even record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), see [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter)

In case of other protocols you will need to find a Java client library for the protocol(s) being used by the application and replicate the application network footprint using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [JUnit Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) or [Java sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) or [write your own JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)